# itext7 Java Create PdfExplicitDestination for titles in existing pdf

Tags: java, pdf, position, bookmarks, itext7

I am using PdfExplicitDestination as a page number, for titles by reading the existing pdf content from the page,

but I need to point the focus on specific text content while click on the bookmark.

```
for (int page = 1; page <= pdf.getNumberOfPages(); page++) {
    ITextExtractionStrategy strategy = new SimpleTextExtractionStrategy();
    String currentText = PdfTextExtractor.getTextFromPage(pdf.getPage(page), strategy);
    if (currentText.contains("title")) {
        k.addDestination(PdfExplicitDestination.createXYZ(pdf.getPage(page), pdf.getPage(page).getPageSize().getLeft(), pdf.getPage(page).getPageSize().getTop(), 0));
        //System.out.println(currentText);
        }
    }
```

I need to find the position of the title in the pdf page to set "float top" value.

```
PdfExplicitDestination.createXYZ(pageNum, left, top, zoom)
```

Can any one please help to get it from the existing content in the pdf.

Answer (score 1):

This task can be approached in a number of ways. One of the way is to go over page content in "stripes" (rectangles with small height), and only consider content from such a small rectangle at a time. If you find a text piece in such rectangle then you know that somewhere between upper and lower bound of Y position given by the rectangle coordinates lies the desired text content. You can e.g. create the destination to point to the topmost coordinate in that case - it might be a bit above the desired text but the difference will be small depending on the rectangle height you select.

The following code snipped contains example implementation of the presented idea. There are two parameters - `windowHeight` which must be tall enough to fit a piece of content you are looking for, but the smaller this variable is the better accuracy you get in the result. Parameter `step` defines how many such rectangles of height `windowHeight` we will try on each page. The smaller the parameter is the better accuracy you get, but bigger parameter values optimize performance. Up to a specific use case to tweak those trade-offs.

```
final float windowHeight = 30;
final float step = 10;

for (int page = 1; page <= pdf.getNumberOfPages(); page++) {
    Rectangle pageSize = pdf.getPage(page).getPageSize();
    for (float upperPoint = pageSize.getHeight(); upperPoint > 0; upperPoint -= step)  {
        IEventFilter filter = new TextRegionEventFilter(new Rectangle(0, upperPoint - windowHeight, pageSize.getWidth(), windowHeight));
        LocationTextExtractionStrategy strategy = new LocationTextExtractionStrategy();
        FilteredTextEventListener listener = new FilteredTextEventListener(strategy, filter);
        new PdfCanvasProcessor(listener).processPageContent(pdf.getPage(page));
        if (strategy.getResultantText().contains("title")) {
            float top = upperPoint; // This is the topmost point of the rectangle
            break; // Break here not to capture same text twice
        }
    }
}
```